# foreach para barrer (iterar) sobre colecciones de objetos

Tags: lista, bucle-for

buen día Comunidad, pueden orientarme sobre las colecciones de datos
intento pasar un objeto que contiene los siguientes parámetros

```
//Obtener ID's correspondientes 
listaIDS=buscaId(listaTrafico,trafico, operadores, monedas, lineaNegocio);


//Asigna los Id a los elementos de la lista
 listaTrafico=validaAsignaDatos(listaTrafico,listaIDS, arrOperador, arrMoneda, arrTrafico, listaErrores);
```

esas dos lineas de código llaman una colección de datos de una BD llamada Pruebas

y de las cuales se desprenden las siguientes listas

```
 List<Claves> listaIDS = new List<Claves>();
   List<Errores> listaErrores = new List<Errores>();
   List<DatosTraficoLDI> listaTrafico = new List<DatosTraficoLDI>();
   List<DatosTraficoLDI> listaTraficoCompleta = new List<DatosTraficoLDI>();
```

de estas mismas obtiene los siguientes datos. por ejemplo de una lista

```
 public partial class DatosTraficoLDI
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Franchise { get; set; }
    public string Billed_Product { get; set; }
    public string Rating_Component { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Billing_Operator { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Unit_Cost_User { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Calls { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Actual_Usage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Charge_Usage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Iva { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Sobrecargo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NumeroCarga { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Id_Carga { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> id_movimiento { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> id_servicio { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> id_grupo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> id_deudor { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> id_acreedor { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> id_trafico { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> estatus { get; set; }
    public string validacion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> fecha_proceso { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> fecha_contable { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> id_moneda { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> tarifa_final { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> cantidad { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> importe { get; set; }
    public string no_factura_referencia { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> monto_facturado { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> prov_nc_registrada { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ajuste { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> nc_emitida { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> saldo_prov_ncr_registrada { get; set; }
    public string motivo_ajuste { get; set; }
    public string periodo_ajuste { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> fecha_ajuste { get; set; }
    public string responsable_ajuste { get; set; }
    public string sociedad_sap { get; set; }
    public string sociedad { get; set; }
    public string nombre_empresa { get; set; }
}
```

}

y ahora mi duda es como puedo usar un foreach para barrer (iterar) sobre colecciones de objetos. de estos objetos

```
 //Obtener ID's correspondientes 
 listaIDS=buscaId(listaTrafico,trafico, operadores, monedas, lineaNegocio);

//Asigna los Id a los elementos de la lista
listaTrafico=validaAsignaDatos(listaTrafico,listaIDS, arrOperador, arrMoneda, arrTrafico, listaErrores);
```

tengo esto pero la verdad no estoy seguro de que este bien. Pueden darme un ejemplo o corregirme si esta erróneo

```
List<Claves> listaIDS = new List<Claves>();

        var lista1 = new List<string>();
        lista1.Add("Id"); //int 
        lista1.Add("Franchise");//string
        lista1.Add("Billed_Product");//string
        lista1.Add("Rating_Component");//string
        lista1.Add("Billing_Operator"); //int 
        lista1.Add("Unit_Cost_User"); //decimal
        lista1.Add("Month");//string
        lista1.Add("Calls"); //decimal
        lista1.Add("Actual_Usage"); //decimal
        lista1.Add("Charge_Usage"); //decimal
        lista1.Add("Amount"); //decimal
        lista1.Add("Iva"); //decimal
        lista1.Add("Sobrecargo"); //decimal
        lista1.Add(" NumeroCarga"); //int 
        lista1.Add("Direccion"); //string
        lista1.Add("Id_Carga"); //int
        lista1.Add("id_movimiento"); //int 
        lista1.Add("id_servicio"); //int 
        lista1.Add("id_grupo"); //int
        lista1.Add("id_deudor"); //int 
        lista1.Add("id_acreedor"); //int 
        lista1.Add("id_trafico"); //int 
        lista1.Add("estatus"); //int 
        lista1.Add("validacion");//string
        lista1.Add("fecha_proceso"); //datetime
        lista1.Add("fecha_contable");//dattime
        lista1.Add("id_moneda"); //int 
        lista1.Add("tarifa_final"); //decimal
        lista1.Add("cantidad"); //decimnal
        lista1.Add("importe"); //decimal
        lista1.Add("no_factura_referencia");
        lista1.Add("monto_facturado"); //decimal
        lista1.Add("prov_nc_registrada"); //decimal
        lista1.Add("ajuste"); //decimal
        lista1.Add("nc_emitida");//decimnal
        lista1.Add("saldo_prov_ncr_registrada");//decimal
        lista1.Add("motivo_ajuste");//string
        lista1.Add("periodo_ajuste");//string
        lista1.Add("fecha_ajuste ");//datetime
        lista1.Add("responsable_ajuste");//string
        lista1.Add("sociedad_sap");//string
        lista1.Add("sociedad");//string
        lista1.Add("nombre_empresa");//string


        for (var index = 0; index < lista1.Count; index++)
        {



        }
```

Comment: espero haberme explicado, de lo contrario díganmelo para re formular la explicación :P

Comment: Quieres recorrer todas las listas que haces o quieres saber como acomodar mejor tus listas?, si quieres recorrer podrías usar LINQ

Comment: si eso, quiero 
podrías por favor darme un ejemplo de como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la lista que tienes `var lista1 = new List<string>();` puedes filtrar sus valores en una sola linea con LINQ

```
var clave = "sociedad";

 //retorna una lista donde su valor sea igual a clave = "sociedad"
 var claveValor = lista1.Where(x => x == clave);
```

o puedes hacer el barrido que quieres con:

```
lista1.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

donde yo puse el Console.Writeline puedes poner una sentencia ejemplo:

```
 lista1.ForEach(x => {
        if (x.Length > 3) 
            Console.WriteLine(x);
    });
```

puedes buscar la documentación de LINQ para ver que hace cada metodo

Comment: Muchas Gracias Black Hole

Comment: De nada, espero que te sirva, alguna otra duda dimelo @SandovalMoralesAdrian